# Fining the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{2^k*z^{2k}}{k^2+k}$

Tags: power-series

I have been trying to get the radius of convergence of this expression $\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{2^k*z^{2k}}{k^2+k}$ by using the ratio test. However I keep getting $\frac{1}{2}$ and the answers say the solution is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, could anyone explain me why they get this answer? Thanks!

Comment: The series has $z^2$ everywhere, so it converges for $|z^2| < 1/2$.

Comment: Thanks! THat las comment makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that in order to be this series to be considered a *power series*, we have to take the general sequence in accord to the "power", which is $\;k\;$  **of** $\;z^2\;$ , **not of** $\;z\;$ .

You can apply Cauchy-Haddamard's formula for the whole thing instead of only for the coefficients in order to avoid confussions:

$$\sqrt[k]{\frac{2^k|z|^{2k}}{k^2+k}}=\frac{2|z|^2}{\sqrt[k]{k^2+k}}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}2|z|^2<1\iff|z|<\frac1{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the Cauchy-Haddamard formula of the form $R=\frac{1}{limsup |a_k|^{1/k}}$?

Comment: @urpi Of course...or $\;\frac1R=\lim\sup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\;$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^k z^{2k}}{k^2+k}$$
Using the ratio test, we have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{2^{n+1} z^{2n+2}}{(n+1)^2+n+1}}{\frac{2^n z^{2n}}{n^2+n}}\right|$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2^{n+1} z^{2n+2}n(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)2^n z^{2n}}\right|$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2^{n}2 z^{2n}z^{2}n}{(n+2)2^n z^{2n}}\right|$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2n z^{2}}{n+2}\right|$$
$$=2 \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{z^2}{1+\frac2n}\right|$$
$$=2 \left|z^2\right|$$
Therefore
$$2 \left|z^2\right|\lt 1$$
$$\left|z\right|^2\lt \frac12$$
$$\left|z\right|\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: I thought the ratio test only used the coefficients of the series not the $z$'s too.

Comment: @urpi, $z$ is indeed part of the series and the convergence of the series is dependent on the value of $z$.